# Proc Sort Using a Macro

Tags: sas

I created 40 plus tables (using a marco, which I just learned how to do) that I would like to apply the Proc Sort statement to. I want each table sorted by the same variable 'Account_Description' (each table contains this variable).

The table names are June_53410_v1, June_53420_v1, June_53430_v1, etc. Can I employ a macro, and if so, how can I, to mitigate having to write a proc sort statement for each table?

Thanks!

I found this sample code online but I'm not really sure how it works

```
 %Macro sorter(dsn, var);
 proc sort data=&dsn.;
 by &var.;
 run;
 %mend;
 %sorter(sample_dataset, age);
```

Comment: I'm reading this and really thinking that whatever you're doing likely shouldn't be using a macro but should be using by group processing. You know you can have multiple BY variables?  Either way, here's a tutorial on changing a working program to a macro and how to run it for all value, it's fairly error proof to create a macro this way. https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Turning%20a%20program%20into%20a%20macro.md

Comment: One might guess the table structures are identical or highly similar, in which case, a very effective scheme would be to stack all the data in one data set and add one or more columns to migrate the 'data' *month name* *number* *version* into the single table.  At that point you can utilize SAS features such as `BY` `CLASS` `WHERE` to perform lots of group-wise processing in one step, or perform group-wise processing on a select set of 'tables'

Comment: Is this a one off task?  Why not just copy the PROC SORT step 40 times and change the dataset names? Or if you going to run the original macro again just add code to the original macro so that it generates the datasets in the proper sorted order.

Comment: Please check, the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Macro that will be used *(proc sort write to work)*:

```
%Macro sorter(lib,dsn, var);
proc sort data=&lib..&dsn. out=&dsn.;
by &var.;
run;
%mend;
```

Get dictionary of tables that contains in name some chars *(its maby “June_” instead “AIR”)* :

```
data sashelp_tables;
set sashelp.vtable;
where LIBNAME="SASHELP" and MEMNAME contains "AIR"
;
run;
```

Write code to string , and execute it for all tables:

```
data _NULL_;
length code $ 200;
set sashelp_tables;
code=cat('%sorter(',LIBNAME,',',MEMNAME,',AIR);');
call execute(code);
run;
```

Comment: @Thanks!   When I run the second step, the log says 0 observations in the SASHELP.VTABLE, should I be putting all of my tables(June_53410_v1, June_53420_v1, June_53430_v...) in the SET statement here?

Comment: @Raven Dataset VTABLE keep all META information about all tables. By condition you choose only tables that you need. did you correct LIBNAME ?

Comment: @sanek_zhitnik, no i did not, what should the LIBNAME be? Sorry, I'm lost here.

Comment: @Raven Yeah! replace my condition to `where MEMNAME contains "June_";` . You will see table , that contains meta information (name,library ...) of tables that gets by condition.

Comment: Thanks, still think im missing something though-the following code:                                                                            
data sashelp_tables;
set sashelp.vtable;
where LIBNAME="SASHELP" and MEMNAME contains "June_";
run;                                                                                                                                               Shows NOTE: There were 0 observations read from the data set SASHELP.VTABLE.WHERE (LIBNAME='SASHELP') and MEMNAME contains 'June_';

Comment: I also have a number of tables that are not labelled June, I have tables that begin with every month (Jan, Feb, March...)

Comment: execute this: 'data sashelp_tables;
set sashelp.vtable;
where  MEMNAME contains "June_"
;
run;'

Comment: @Raven That tables in separate Libname?

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate everyone's input-I think I found an answer though using this code:

```
 %macro st (ds);
 proc sort data = &ds;
 by Account_Description;
 run;
 %mend;

 %st(June_53410_v1); 
 %st(June_53420_v1);
```

Comment: How is that any easier than just writing the PROC SORT statements?

Comment: I don't have to write a PROC SORT statement for every one of my tables.

Comment: Your editor doesn't support copy and paste? Either way the amount of new typing is the same.

Comment: It does, I was just looking for a more efficient and cleaner way to write the code, which the above achieves. Instead of copying and pasting the proc sort step every time, I just type %st(table_name1); %st(table_name2); and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution, where lib is libname, mask_table is mask to table(June_ in your task) and var is variable to sort tables:

```
 %macro sorter(lib,mask_table, var); %macro d;%mend d;

       %let table_list = 0;

       proc sql noprint;
          select strip(libname) || '.' || strip(memname),count(memname)
          into: table_list separated by ' '
          from dictionary.tables 
          where libname = UPCASE("&lib.") and memname LIKE UPCASE("&mask_table.")||"%";
       quit;

       %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&table_list,%str( )));
          %let name&i = %scan(&table_list, &i, %str( ));
          proc sort data=&&name&i.;
             by &var.;
          run;
       %end;

  %mend sorter;
  %sorter(WORK,June,Account_Description);
```